# Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1

Tags: php, regex

I receive the following error message:

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1
```

And this is the line of code that is giving me this trouble.

```
$tag_value = preg_replace('/\{(.*?)\}/e', '$values[\\1]', $tag_value);
```

I am using PHP 5.2.9 and upgrading is not an option.

Regular expression are not my specialty and I am not able to solve this problem on my own. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Works for me](http://3v4l.org/oq6QY).

Comment: @krishna: `\\1` is not a typo. It refers to the first backreference. Combined with the `e` modifier, this will result in `\\1` being replaced with what was captured in the first capturing group in the regex, i.e. the content between `{...}`. The replacement parameter needs to be changed to `'$values["\\1"]'` though (or else, it would most likely complain about an undefined constant).

Comment: @AmalMurali Oh then sorry for wrong info and thanks for information..

Comment: Looks like this has something to do with namespaces. See [this demo](http://3v4l.org/CsLNU#v442). I don't think `preg_replace()` is what's causing this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot accomplish this with a simple `preg_replace`, as array de-referencing is not done with `/e` modifier.  Instead you can use `preg_replace_callback` function:

```
$tag_value = preg_replace_callback("/\{(.*?)\}/", function($m) use($values){
    return $values[$m[1]];
}, $tag_value);
```

This definitely works in php 5.3, however in 5.2 you may need to define the callback function explicitly:

```
function replace($m) {
    global $values;
    return $values[$m[1]];
}
$tag_value = preg_replace_callback("/\{(.*?)\}/", "replace", $tag_value);
```

**EDIT:** The error you are seeing is happening because with your original code, your substitution is being treated literally as `$values[\1]` (after unescaping the backslash - in this string, `\1` is not the right stuff to put inside the brackets.

Comment: `preg_replace_callback()` is indeed the right solution here, but I think the OP is trying to solve the error "*Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1*".

Comment: @AmalMurali I think ultimately the OP wants to get the code working. However, for completeness sake, I'm updating the answer with the explanation of the error.